# Php not reading date as <= to current date correctly

Tags: php, date

I have tried every combo I can think of / found and no matter what I do, my codet echos the message even if the account isn't locked out:

```
<?php
    $infosql = "SELECT * FROM premiersounds_users WHERE customer_id = $id";
    $inforesult = mysql_query($infosql) or die(mysql_error());
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($inforesult);

    //Get current date from server
    $format="%m/%d/%y";
    $c_date=strftime($format);
    //set sessions
    $_SESSION['current_date'] = $c_date;
    //The date in the database is 10/31/11
    $_SESSION['lockout_date'] = $l_date;

    //Check is Current date = lockout date

    if ($c_date <= $l_date) { 
        header("location:documnet_editors/edit_weddingplanner.php?id=$id"); 
    } 

    else {
        echo 'Whoops! Were sorry your account has been locked to edits 
        because your event is less than 48 hours from now or your event has passed. 
    To make changes to your event please contact your DJ.';
    }

?>

<?php
    //Destroy Session for Lockout Date to prevent bypasses
    unset($_SESSION['lockout_date']);
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$l_date` defined?  It's not in your sample.

Comment: Seriously, how could you not put that in the question

Comment: @TylerRadlick: Just FYI, 'session' and 'cookie' are two completely different things. Yes they are both persistant, to some degree, but cookies are browser based, and session is server based. What the others are implying is that you're setting $_SESSION['current&lockout_date'] equal to $c&l_date, but you're not populating $c&l_date in this code, and then you're doing your if off of $c&l_date, not your session vars.

Comment: Heres the code where l_date is set from the top of the page `<?php
$infosql = "SELECT * FROM premiersounds_users WHERE customer_id = $id";
$inforesult = mysql_query($infosql) or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($inforesult);


$l_date=$info['lockout_date']; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your $l_date is populated, and I don't think it is, if it is stored as MM/DD/YY, you'll want to use PHP's strtotime to convert it to a unix timestamp for quick comparison:

```
if( strtotime($db_date) >= time() )
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your dates to unixtime for more accurate comparison. Add this function to your code:

```
 function unix_time($date){  
    $unix_date = str_replace("-","/",$date);
    $unix_date = str_replace(".","/",$unix_date);
    $unix_date = str_replace(" pm","",$unix_date);
    $unix_date = str_replace(" am","",$unix_date);
    $time = strtotime($unix_date);
    return $time;
 }
```

then convert the dates to unix:

```
$l_date = unix_time($_SESSION['lockout_date']);
$c_date = unix_time($_SESSION['current_date']);
```

or you can also get the date directly from the database:

```
 $l_date = unix_time($info['date_in_database']);
```

compare the dates in unix format:

```
if ($c_date = $l_date) {
    // your code here
}
```

this should work.

Comment: He already states that his date is stored in the format "10/31/11", which will be interpreted by strtotime as a US time type, and parse out the month and day accordingly. And secondly, $c_date is the current time, so there is no reason not to just save processing overhead and use the built in time() function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest comparing timestamps instead of formatted dates:

```
<?php
$date_a = new DateTime();
$date_b = new DateTime('2000-10-20 00:10:20');
if ($date_a->getTimestamp() > $date_b->getTimestamp()) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```